# Add function to individual XmlListModel items

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I am new to QML and Qt Quick and was wondering how I can add functions to each individual item in an [XmlListModel](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qml-xmllistmodel.html).

```
XmlListModel {
  id: books
  source: "Books.xml"
  query: "/books"
  XmlRole { name: "price"; query: "@price/string()" }
}
```

Say the price is in cents and I want to multiply each price by a factor 100. In another programming language I would add a `getPrice()` function on the `Book` class but I don't have access to the individual elements here. I could add it to the XmlListModel with an index parameter but I feel it belongs to the individual book item, no?

Comment: Be sure to read the [Models and Views document](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html) to clarify any doubts about delegates and models. Apart from that, I wouldn't be wrong but I think you can query the price with `number()` instead of `string()` and in the  delegate just write `text: price * 100`. Actually, since the query conform AFAIK to `xpath` specifications, it would be possible to query and multiply in one row, i.e. `@price/number() * 100` (check it). Another approach is the one proposed by @folibis: extract the `string` and pass it to a function inside delegate.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo: I was looking for a generic way to access data within a collection, not an XPath specific solution... but I do think you approach is the cleanest solution for the example I provided. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. My intent was to just present another approach. That's it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code above you just defined model and roles to fetch data, not real data. But you can access data itself and data items particularly in `delegate`, for example:

```
ListView {
    id: listView
    anchors.fill: parent
    function getPrice(value) {
        return value * 100;
    }
    model: books
    delegate: Row {
        height: 30
        width: parent.width
        Text { text: listView.getPrice(price) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I would go for an XPath approach, as stated in the other comment. But surely also this approach works. :)

Comment: Thank you, passing the price parameter still feels a bit odd but I have to learn to think like a QML developer now. ;)